# bootstrap row pseudo elements usage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im wondering and dont know the answer for Bootstrap Grid row using Display:table and content:"" for their pseudo elements(after and before) . Why it is using display table there .

```
.row:after,.row:before{
display:table;
}
```

Can anyone explain why they using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.row:before, .row:after { display: table; }

This is supported by all browsers except for IE(6/7). It generates a pseudo-element before and after the content of the element that contains floats. Setting display: table creates an anonymous  table-cell and a new block formatting context. This acts to prevent top-margin collapse and improve the consistency between modern browsers and IE(6/7).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. cant understand top-margin collapse ?

Comment: The expression collapsing margins means that adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding or border areas or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to one another or nested) combine to form a single margin. The resulting margin width is the maximum of the adjoining margin widths. In CSS 2.1, horizontal margins never collapse. For more information follow this link you will be clear----------> http://960development.com/understand-css-margins-collapsing/